# Can't connect to Linux MySQL DB from Windows 10 via ODBC

Tags: mysql, linux, windows-10, odbc

There is a Linux MySQL DB we have connect to. This works fine on Windows 7 computers. Now there is Window 10 an no connection anymore. (Windows XP worked so too)

*Server version: 5.1.73-1 (Debian)*

I used the same parameters as on the Windows 7 machines. (ODBC driver 5.1, 32Bit - "mysql-connector-odbc-noinstall-5.1.13-win32")

- The same driver (I tried version 5.3 32Bit too)
- The same user and password
- the machines are in the same network

The error is "Malformed package".

Connecting a Windows DB works.

(The machine may not have an Internet connection.)

Error Messages:

MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver

> Connection Failed: [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Connection using old(pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

Altough ist an old server I tried newer drivers:

MySQL 5.3 ANSI Driver

> ConnectionFailed
>   [MySql][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Malformed packet:

MySQL 5.3 Unicode Driver

> ConnectionFailed
>   [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Malformed packet:

MySQL 8.0 ANSI Driver

> ConnectionFailed
>   [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver]Bad handshake:

MySQL 8.0 Unicode Driver

> ConnectionFailed
>   [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Bad handshake:

Comment: Firewall in Windows 10?

Comment: can you connect to the DB from linux?

Comment: @Geno Chen _Firewall_ will be checked

Comment: @user3426711 I don't have linux to try :(

Comment: @AndyU. I mean, can you connect to it from the same linux machine where the DB is hosted..?

Comment: @user3426711 I can't try too, because it's the machine of the customer I have not things to try on.. but I can access the DB from other windows machines, so why try linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a driver problem: 5.1.13 does not work, 5.1.12 is needed! Then it works.

Download link:
mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=411741

see
[MySQL ODBC Link Fails due to "authentication protocol refused"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017354/mysql-odbc-link-fails-due-to-authentication-protocol-refused)